# How can I remove the span wrapper in Contact Form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I use [Contact Form 7](http://contactform7.com/) in my **WordPress** theme.

It is currently returning `span` and `input`:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap name">
  <input type="text" name="name" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" id="name">
</span>
```

But I need only `input`:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" id="name">
```

How can I remove the `span` wrapper?

Answer (score 47):

I faced the same problem and finally ending by using the `wpcf7_form_elements` filter to remove the `<span>` tag with a regex. You can for example copy-paste this code in your `functions.php`file. Here I pass an an anonymous function as a callback, so be sure to have PHP >= 5.3.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', function($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<(span).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?wpcf7-form-control-wrap(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $content);

    return $content;
});
```

Comment: it is working, but it removed the error message too.... I am not familiar with regex.

Comment: @jho1086, this is not a problem with the regex, but the JS in WPCF7. It probably uses the span (that this filter removes) as the target container when adding the error message span. Since the span doesn't exist it doesn't know where to add the error span.

Comment: @Punchlinern so is there a known solution for adding the error span properly using this regex ?

Comment: Hi. Was anyone able to find a solution for the error spans also getting removed?

Answer (score 12):

I tried similar stuff the other day and many people mentioned, that Regex is not the proper way to alter HTML/remove tags etc and it [sounds logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

So i went for [DOMDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and came up with following solution:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', function( $content ) {
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

  $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
  $spans = $xpath->query("//span[contains(@class, 'wpcf7-form-control-wrap')]" );

  foreach ( $spans as $span ) :
    $children = $span->firstChild;
    $span->parentNode->replaceChild( $children, $span );
  endforeach;

  return $dom->saveHTML();
});
```

**EDIT:**
I now also added some html/text to my form, and the first heading element was not wrapping correctly after i used the DOMDocument class. It started in the first line and ended at the very end of the form. so i wrapped my entire form in a div, what made the markup return properly again.

Comment: This is working fine! I just mention changing line 7 if you want to still support Honeypot for Contact Form 7:
`$spans = $xpath->query( "//span[contains(@class, 'wpcf7-form-control-wrap') and not(@style)]" );`

Answer (score 8):

As of WPCF7 version 4.9, adapting the answer above so as to allow for error messaging to not be lost:

First of all, in the editor in the CMS, wrap your input field and any other elements that you want grouped, for example:

```
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">{field codes, etc, here}</span>
```

Note that you'll need to use the class "wpcf7-form-control-wrap" and a class that matches your field name.

Next, use this regex code in your `functions.php`. It may need adapting for your specific needs

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', function($content) {
    preg_match_all('/<(span).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?wpcf7-form-control-wrap(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', $content,$matches);

    foreach($matches[2] as $match):
        $content = str_replace(trim($match),trim(preg_replace('/<(span).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?wpcf7-form-control-wrap(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $match)),$content);
    endforeach;
    return $content;
});
```

This will strip the span tag around the input field while leaving your new span tag intact. The effect is to essentially move the span tag from around only the input field, to being around whatever elements you wish to wrap.

The reason for this is that the code for form submission is unfortunately very hard coded. In order to have complete freedom over the structure of your HTML you would need to either:

1. Change the code in rest-api.php around line 295 to change the "into" value to something less specific. Naturally this isn't a recommended route though the one that gives you complete freedom to structure your content as you wish. It'll be overwritten with plugin updates.

   ```
   foreach ( (array) $result['invalid_fields'] as $name => $field ) {
       $invalid_fields[] = array(
           'into' => 'span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.'
               . sanitize_html_class( $name ),
           'message' => $field['reason'],
           'idref' => $field['idref'],
       );
   }
   ```
2. Tap into the wpcf7:invalid event and run your own validation code on the result. Needless to say this is duplicating a lot of the work the plugin already does for you, when accepting (for now) to use a span tag with the "wpcf7-form-control-wrap" class in the manner described above retains all functionality of the plugin while undoing one of the most annoying hard codings of the plugin.

Answer (score 7):

You can remove the span wrapper using jQuery:

```
$("#name").unwrap();
```

It will remove input's parent element, so in this case it will remove the span.
Please note that after removing the span, some Contact Form 7 features may not work correctly. For example validation may not work.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#name").unwrap();
});
```

```css
span {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap name">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" id="name" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
</span>

<button>Remove span</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This example works for me and shows how to remove `<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap"></span>` input wrapper without getting any errors:

I have combined @Guicara's code

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', function($content) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<(span).*?class="\s*(?:.*\s)?wpcf7-form-control-wrap(?:\s[^"]+)?\s*"[^\>]*>(.*)<\/\1>/i', '\2', $content);

    return $content;
});
```

with @niaccurshi's answer and made some edits.
First, you need to remove `<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">` with code above. Then manually add a `<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap">` with extra class **that matches your field name** to your form template as a wrapper of all fields.
Check example screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me:
$content = preg_replace('/<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>/', '\1', $content);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's old, but still actual problem. Here is the code to output "raw" checkbox|radio without span with id attribute:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_elements', 'contact_form_remove_checkbox_wrapping' );

function contact_form_remove_checkbox_wrapping( $content ) {
    preg_match_all('/<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap[a-zA-Z ]*"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-[checkbox|radio]+" id="([^\"]+)"><span class="[^\"]+">(<input type="[checkbox|radio]+" name="[^\"]+" value="[^\"]*" \/>)<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">[^\"]+<\/span><\/span><\/span><\/span>/i', $content, $out );
    if ( !empty( $out[0] ) ) {
        $count = count( $out[1] );
        for ( $i = 0; $i<$count; $i++ ) {
            $out[2][ $i ] = str_replace(' value=', 'id="' . $out[1][ $i ] . '" value=', $out[2][$i] );
        }

        return str_replace( $out[0], $out[2], $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: This look good but, does not work for me(

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the simple script that adds class to this span when the input is focused(I wanted to use `input:focus + label`, but this span was breaking this logic);

```
/*contact form inputs*/
  var contactFormInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.wpcf7-form-control'); // or your custom input class
  contactFormInputs.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
      event.target.parentElement.classList.add("focused");
    });
    element.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
      event.target.parentElement.classList.remove("focused");
    });
    element.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
     event.target.value
        ? event.target.parentElement.classList.add("valid")
        : event.target.parentElement.classList.remove("valid")
    });
  });
```

So now, I can use

```
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.focused, .wpcf7-form-control-wrap.valid {
  ~ .ui-block-label {
    top: -20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: $yellowDark;
  }
}
```

in my SCSS code.

Comment: Thank you. In my case this answer was the one that helped me!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Guicara's php code, the following javascript code could get the text of the error message:

```
document.addEventListener('wpcf7invalid',function(e){
    if ('validation_failed' === e.detail.apiResponse.status){
        $.each(e.detail.apiResponse.invalidFields,function(i,el){
        console.log('this is error response and form object',el.message, $('#'+el.idref));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Not ideal solution, Solution should be in to PHP.